# BashScript - Sudo as a user, enter in a certain folder and run a command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a newbie to Bash Script, I've been trying to sudo as a certain user, enter in a specific folder and run a command. I tried this command below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -i -u "site"  cd /home/site/public_html && pwd
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -i -u "site" cd /home/site/public_html
sudo -i -u "site" pwd
```

The first one just enters as the user enters in the folder, leaves and send a pwd on my own user
The second one enters as the user enters in the folder, leaves, enters as the user and send a pwd

Any help will be welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `sudo` command starts a new shell process, so process changes done by one command have no effect on the next one.

You need to run everything in a single shell process. You can do this by running `bash` explicitly.

```
sudo -i -u "site" bash -c 'cd /home/site/public_html && pwd'
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a while inside or an if to check output information and based on that execute certain commands?
Example:
sudo -i -u "site" bash -c 'cd /home/site/public_html && if [[ "$a == $b"]] then echo "$c" '

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But if it's getting that complex, you probably should put all the code in a script and execute the script with `sudo`.